# Checking if user exists in text file when registering

Tags: java, swing, bufferedwriter

When making a registration class for registration and login system, it successfully adds the user into the text file. What I am asking is how I can make the program check if user's login ID already exists in text file.

Contents of text file:

```
User{nickname= Barry, loginID= baz15, password= dan}
```

When entering the same details for registering, it adds this again. How can I make it not add this again to the file and instead displays a `JOptionPane`?

I have an array list that references User class to check if the user exists in the text file. This is my code so far:

```
 public class RegistrationJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public RegistrationJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        lblErrorMessage.setVisible(false);
    }


    private void btnRegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String nickname = edtNickname.getText();
        String loginID = edtLoginID.getText();
        String password = String.valueOf(edtPassword.getPassword());
        String confirmPassword = String.valueOf(edtReenterPassword.getPassword());


        if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            lblErrorMessage.setText("Passwords do not match");
        }
        if (nickname.equals("") || loginID.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
            lblErrorMessage.setText("You must fill in  the text fields");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            if (users.get(i).getLoginID().equals(loginID)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User exists in file");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User does not exist");
            }

        }
        try {
            User user = new User(nickname, loginID, password);
            users.add(user);
            File filename = new File("userinfo.txt");
            if (!filename.exists()) {
                filename.createNewFile();
            }


            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(user.toString());
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do all your logic checks *before* you create the User object.

Comment: a simple fix would be to store all users in a data structure on startup, when a user is added, add it to the data structure, then when you want to save or your program ends, you overwrite your file with current state of your user data structure

Comment: @notyou I've moved the User object inside the try-catch block but the problem still happens

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz how would I store the users on startup?

Comment: I tried adding user object to arrayList but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to rewrite your users to the file instead of appending the new user to your file. This means you would just have to loop through the list and rewrite all the users to file each time a new user is created. You could create a saveToFile() method like so and call it

```
private void saveToFile()
{
    try{
        File filename = new File("userinfo.txt");
        if (!filename.exists()) {
            filename.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, false); //false so you don't append and overwrite
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        //now loop your arraylist of users to resave them to your file
        for(User currUser : users)
        {
            bw.write(currUser.toString());
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Next you have to determine when it's ok to add the user and save it. Try using a boolean in your btnRegisterActionPerformed method like this

```
private void btnRegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String nickname = edtNickname.getText();
    String loginID = edtLoginID.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(edtPassword.getPassword());
    String confirmPassword = String.valueOf(edtReenterPassword.getPassword());


    if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
        lblErrorMessage.setText("Passwords do not match");
    }
    if (nickname.equals("") || loginID.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
        lblErrorMessage.setText("You must fill in  the text fields");
    }

    boolean addUser = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        if (users.get(i).getLoginID().equals(loginID)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User exists in file");
            addUser = false;
            break;//no need to keep checking so break out of the for loop
         } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User does not exist");
         }
    }

    if(addUser)
    {
        User user = new User(nickname, loginID, password);
        users.add(user);
        //now save the contents of the list to the file
        saveToFile();
    }
}
```

You are currently always adding the user to your file which is incorrect. We use the boolean to determine if the user does not exist, and only when the user cannot be found do we add the user and save to the file.

Comment: For the Login page using BufferedReader, would this be done in the same way but by replacing saveToFile() with readToFile?

Comment: you'd have to read the file in and parse the file line by line and create the arraylist of User objects so you have something to check against when your user attempts to login

Comment: I've posted the second question regarding the BufferedReader and my issues with it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459403/confused-on-how-to-use-bufferedreader-for-reading-arraylist-of-user-objects)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct I would do it with a separate method:

```
public class RegistrationJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

public RegistrationJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    lblErrorMessage.setVisible(false);
}


private void btnRegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String nickname = edtNickname.getText();
    String loginID = edtLoginID.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(edtPassword.getPassword());
    String confirmPassword = String.valueOf(edtReenterPassword.getPassword());


    if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
        lblErrorMessage.setText("Passwords do not match");
    }
    if (nickname.equals("") || loginID.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
        lblErrorMessage.setText("You must fill in  the text fields");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        if (users.get(i).getLoginID().equals(loginID)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User exists in file");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User does not exist");
            User user = new User(nickname, loginID, password);
            users.add(user);
            saveUser(user);
        }

    }
}        

private void saveUser(User user) {
    try {
        File filename = new File("userinfo.txt");
        if (!filename.exists()) {
            filename.createNewFile();
        }


        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(user.toString());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

}
```

For your file you maybe go better with a json file. Might be easier if you want to add further information to the user.

Comment: And as others said, I'd do the file setup to the program start

Comment: This solution stops it from adding the user twice to the text file but the JOptionPane message dialog does not seem to pop up.